# iframe issue in IE-8 and IE-9 when edit row in gridview

Tags: asp.net, iframe, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9

I am using iframe in jquery popup showing a page content.

in that page I am using gridview for list of data.

When I am editing gridview It doesn't show me an error but the inline edit TextBox not displaying in IE-8 and IE-9, While same thing is displaying in IE-7, Firefox and Chrome.

So, that I have try the same page without iframe in IE-8 and IE-9, now the inline editing is working fine.

can anybody know what is the problem and how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason behind is that IE-8, and IE-9 doesn't allow to change the iframe content. due to security.